# Dockware/Shopware Unable to Connect to Database from a graphical database management (DBeaver)

Tags: shopware, dbeaver

I'm experiencing difficulties connecting to the MySql Dockware Database through DBeaver. I simply want to establish a connection, but I encounter an error, specifically `!AuthenticationProvider.BadAuthenticationPlugin!`, whether I use the connection URL or input the host and password credentials. I'm uncertain whether this issue stems from DBeaver or if it's related to Dockware/Shopware.

I attempted to use the URL provided by Dockware documentation, `mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/shopware`, but it didn't work. I also tried using just the root credentials, and that was unsuccessful as well. Is there something I might be overlooking?

Comment: If anyone is wondering, yeah I use the URL that appears in the .env file in the Dockware/Shopware project.